# is chromium browser less cpu-intensive than google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I mostly use *Google Chrome* for my browsing, it's startup speed is good for my taste. Few days past, I was working in office computer and found another browser, *Chromium*. I searched for details and I found that Google takes it's(chromium) functions and features for *Chrome*, that way I thing *Chromium* has vast features to discover. So I want to replace *Chrome* for *Chromium*. Most irritating issue on *Chrome* is it's very CPU-intensive. So I want to know that is *Chromium* less intensive or same?? If same then it won't do any work for me. Please help. Thank you.

P.S please don't suggest me other browsers, because that isn't my concern!

P.P.S who don't have knowledge in this please don't put irrational comments!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is basically Chromium with a few additional closed bits and Google branding.  so no, there won't really be a difference between running Chromium & Chrome wrt resource utilization.

keep in mind there are other factors that might matter -- Chromium does not include Adobe Flash for example.